# Dynamically add tabs to tab control

Tags: xaml, tabcontrol, controltemplate, tabitem

I am trying to dynamically add tabs to tab control. I have control template in resources:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="memoTab" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">  
    <TabItem Header="Memo">  
        <TextBox Name="memoText"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    </TabItem>  
</ControlTemplate>
```

I create tab in code behind:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();  
tab.Template = (ControlTemplate) FindResource("memoTab");  
tab.ApplyTemplate();  
TextBox tb = (TextBox) tab.Template.FindName("memoText", tab);  
tb.DataContext = memo; //this is a string created by linq query  
tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

I end up with tab visible in tab control, but it is not selectable, and I cannot see anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce it, try this way instead:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var content = new TextBlock();
    content.Text = "Hello World! " + new Random().Next(1, 20).ToString();

    TabItem tab = new TabItem();
    tab.Header = "Hello world!";
    tab.Content = content;
    tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

UI

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="Existing tab 1" />
        <TabItem Header="Existing tab 2" />
    </TabControl>

    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Add Tab" Width="100" Height="30" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps!